# Why does my .h5 model predicts well on jupyter notebook but .tflite file predicts poorly in android studio

Tags: android-studio, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook

I have trained my dataset consisting of 11,000+ images using Resnet50 architecture, it has 83 classes, and I have sample images that can correctly be classified.
Here is the code for training:

Data generator:

```
data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(horizontal_flip=True,
                                   width_shift_range = 0.4,
                                   height_shift_range = 0.4,
                                   zoom_range=0.3,
                                   rotation_range=20,                                    
                                   )

image_size = 224
to_res = (224, 224)
batch_size = 10
train_generator = data_generator.flow_from_directory(
        'C:\\Users\\Mer3\\Desktop\\Final\\train',
        target_size=(image_size, image_size),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='categorical')

test_generator = data_generator.flow_from_directory(
        'C:\\Users\\Mer3\\Desktop\\Final2\\test',
        target_size=(image_size, image_size),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='categorical',shuffle=False)

num_classes = len(train_generator.class_indices)
```

Model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(K.layers.Lambda(lambda image: tf.image.resize(image, to_res)))
model.add(ResNet50(include_top=False, pooling='avg', weights='imagenet')) 
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(2048, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.layers[0].trainable = False
```

**The problem is** it classifies images correctly after training on pyhton as I wished in [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqs49.jpg).

But when i convert the h5 file to .tflite file with the following code snipplet,

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("resnet50_100epochs.h5")
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("resnet50_100epochs.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

And integrated it into an android studio project using
Image classifier class

```
package com.example.tez;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;

import org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull;
import org.tensorflow.lite.DataType;
import org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.common.FileUtil;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.common.TensorProcessor;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.common.ops.NormalizeOp;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.image.ImageProcessor;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.image.TensorImage;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.image.ops.ResizeOp;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.image.ops.ResizeWithCropOrPadOp;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.image.ops.Rot90Op;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.label.TensorLabel;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.tensorbuffer.TensorBuffer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class ImageClassifier {

    private static final float PROBABILTY_MEAN = 0.0f; 
    private static final float PROBABILTY_STD = 255f;  
    private static final float IMAGE_MEAN = 128.0f;       
    private static final float IMAGE_STD =  128.0f ;   
    private static final int MAX_SIZE = 3 ;
    private final Interpreter tensorClassifier;
    private final int imageResizeX ;
    private final  List<String> labels;
    private final int imageResizeY;
    private TensorImage inputImageBuffer;
    private final TensorBuffer probabiltyImageBuffer;
    private final TensorProcessor probabilityProcessor;

    public ImageClassifier(Activity activity) throws IOException {
         MappedByteBuffer classifierModel = FileUtil.loadMappedFile(activity,
                 "resnet50_100epochs.tflite");
        labels = FileUtil.loadLabels(activity, "labels_mantar.txt");

        tensorClassifier = new Interpreter(classifierModel, null);

        int imageTensorIndex = 0; //input
        int probabilityTensorIndex = 0; //output

        int[] inputimagerShape = tensorClassifier.getInputTensor(imageTensorIndex).shape();
        DataType inputDataType = tensorClassifier.getInputTensor(imageTensorIndex).dataType();

        int[] outputImageShape = tensorClassifier.getOutputTensor(probabilityTensorIndex).shape();
        DataType outputDataType = tensorClassifier.getOutputTensor(probabilityTensorIndex).dataType();

        imageResizeX = inputimagerShape[1];
        imageResizeY = inputimagerShape[2];

        inputImageBuffer = new TensorImage(inputDataType);

        probabiltyImageBuffer = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(outputImageShape, outputDataType);

        probabilityProcessor = new TensorProcessor.Builder().add(new NormalizeOp(PROBABILTY_MEAN, PROBABILTY_STD))
                .build();
    }

    public List<Recognition> recognizeImage(final Bitmap bitmap, final int sensorOrientation){
        List<Recognition> recognitions = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Recognition> recognitions2 = new ArrayList<>();
        inputImageBuffer = loadImage(bitmap, sensorOrientation);
        tensorClassifier.run(inputImageBuffer.getBuffer(), probabiltyImageBuffer.getBuffer().rewind());
        Map<String, Float> labeledProbabilty = new TensorLabel(labels,
                probabilityProcessor.process(probabiltyImageBuffer)).getMapWithFloatValue();
        for(Map.Entry<String, Float> entry : labeledProbabilty.entrySet()){
            recognitions.add(new Recognition(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));

        }

        Collections.sort(recognitions);
        recognitions.subList(0, MAX_SIZE > recognitions.size() ? recognitions.size() : MAX_SIZE).clear();
        recognitions2.add(recognitions.get(0));
        //return recognitions2;
        return recognitions;

    }

    private TensorImage loadImage(Bitmap bitmap, int sensorOrientation) {
        inputImageBuffer.load(bitmap);
        int noOfRotations = sensorOrientation / 90;
        int cropSize = Math.min(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
       // System.out.println("CROP SIZE "+ cropSize);
       // int cropSize = 253;
        System.out.println(cropSize);
        ImageProcessor imageProcessor = new ImageProcessor.Builder()
                .add(new ResizeWithCropOrPadOp(cropSize, cropSize))
                .add(new ResizeOp(imageResizeX,imageResizeY,ResizeOp.ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOR))
                .add(new Rot90Op(noOfRotations))
                .add(new NormalizeOp(IMAGE_MEAN,IMAGE_STD))
                .build();
        return imageProcessor.process(inputImageBuffer);

    }

   public class Recognition implements Comparable {
        private String name;
        private float confidence;

        public Recognition() {
        }

        public Recognition(String name, float confidence) {
            this.name = name;
            this.confidence = confidence;
        }

         public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public float getConfidence() {
            return confidence;
        }

        public void setConfidence(float confidence) {
            this.confidence = confidence;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Recognition{" +
                    "name='" + name + '\'' +
                    ", confidence=" + confidence +
                    '}';
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Object o) {
            return Float.compare(((Recognition) o).confidence, this.confidence);
        }
    }
}
```

The prediction for the same input picture is false, here is a screenshot of the prediction [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwEYt.jpg)

**I tried** changing IMG_MEAN and IMG_STD to 0 and 255 respectively but still false predictions.
Any help is appreciated so much.

Comment: Convert your saved model to frozen graph and followed by tflite model. Check the similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/51881268/14290244

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i will try it soon. @TFer